# Why hierarchical clustering can not see numeric attributes?

Tags: java, weka, hierarchical-clustering

I'm toying with Java, Weka and IP addresses. Now I'm trying to do hierarchical clustering with dataset: source and destination IPv4 (converted to decimal) and protocol - all received from Wireshark log.

I keep addresses and protocols in lists and build dataset the way from manual

```
    FastVector atts = new FastVector();
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("from"));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("to"));
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("protocol", (FastVector)null));
    Instances data = new Instances("Connections", atts, 0);

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        double[] vals = new double[data.numAttributes()];
        // Get address from list and with special method convert it to long
        vals[0] = from.get(i).getDecimal();
        vals[1] = to.get(i).getDecimal();
        // Protocol - String like "TCP"
        vals[2] = data.attribute(2).addStringValue(protocol.get(i));
        data.add(new Instance(1.0, vals));
     }

    HierarchicalClusterer hc = new HierarchicalClusterer();
    //hc.setDebug(true);
    hc.setPrintNewick(true);
    hc.setNumClusters(4);
    hc.buildClusterer(data);

    System.out.print(hc);
```

When I print some random Instance from data I can see that everything is ok. But in output of clustering there are only informations about protocols. eg (it's only small part).

> Cluster 1
>   ((MSNMS:0,MSNMS:0):0,MSNMS:0)

Output with debugging option is something like

> Merging 0 4 0.0 0.0
>
> Merging 0 5 0.0 0.0
>
> Merging 1 7 0.0 0.0

Am I doing something wrong or... the whole idea of clustering dataset like this is just stupid?

Comment: Can you specify your question?